# How to reference hypertables properly using foreign key constraints in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, django-rest-framework, foreign-keys, timescaledb, hypertable

**#Error description:**
It's possible to create a table that has a foreign key into a hypertable provided the foreign key is defined when the table is created

**#To Reproduce, there are next tables:**

```
CREATE TABLE ids ( 
    measurement_id int DEFAULT 0,        
    description text DEFAULT 0,       
    m_id bigserial NOT NULL,
    service_id int  DEFAULT NULL,     
    time bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT cast((EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM now() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC') * 1000) as bigint),
    user_id int  DEFAULT NULL,
    end_time DOUBLE PRECISION DEFAULT 0,     
    start_time int NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
);

CREATE INDEX ON ids (time DESC, user_id);
CREATE INDEX ON ids (time DESC, service_id);

SELECT create_hypertable('ids', 'start_time', chunk_time_interval => 604800016);

---------

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS metrics (
  id bigserial NOT NULL, 
  duration real DEFAULT NULL, 
  metric integer DEFAULT 0,   
  m_id bigint NOT NULL,
  time bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT 0   
);

ALTER TABLE metrics ADD PRIMARY KEY (time, m_id);

CREATE INDEX ON metrics (time DESC);
CREATE INDEX ON metrics (time DESC, measurement );
CREATE INDEX ON metrics (time DESC, m_id );

grant all privileges on ids, metrics to your_db_user;

SELECT create_hypertable('metrics', 'time' , chunk_time_interval => 604800016);

SELECT table_catalog, table_schema, table_name, privilege_type FROM  information_schema.table_privileges WHERE  grantee = 'your_db_user';

---------

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS resource;
CREATE TABLE resource(
id          int NOT NULL,
cpu         text DEFAULT 0,
storing     text DEFAULT 0,
memory      text DEFAULT 0
); 

ALTER TABLE resource ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);

CREATE SEQUENCE resource_id_seq
  INCREMENT 1
  MINVALUE 1
  MAXVALUE 2147483647
  START 1
  CACHE 1;
ALTER TABLE resource_id_seq
  OWNER TO your_db_user;

ALTER TABLE resource ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT nextval('resource_id_seq'::regclass);

---------

CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ns;

CREATE TABLE ns(
id                    bigint NOT NULL,
uuid                  uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4 (),
availability          double precision,
faultTolerance        boolean,
activated             boolean,     
UNIQUE (id, uuid),
PRIMARY KEY(id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_resource
     FOREIGN KEY(id)
         REFERENCES resource(id)
         ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE SEQUENCE ns_id_seq
  INCREMENT 1
  MINVALUE 1
  MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
  START 1
  CACHE 1;
ALTER TABLE ns_id_seq
  OWNER TO your_db_user;

ALTER TABLE ns ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT nextval('ns_id_seq'::regclass);

---------

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS authentication;

CREATE TABLE authentication(
id                    integer NOT NULL,
username              character varying(255) NOT NULL,
password              character varying(255) NOT NULL,
host                  character varying(255) NOT NULL,
port                  character varying(10) NOT NULL,    
PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

CREATE SEQUENCE auth_id_seq
  INCREMENT 1
  MINVALUE 1
  MAXVALUE 2147483647
  START 1
  CACHE 1;
ALTER TABLE auth_id_seq
  OWNER TO your_db_user;

ALTER TABLE authentication ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT nextval('auth_id_seq'::regclass);

---------

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS job;

CREATE TABLE job(
id                    int NOT NULL,
interval              integer NOT NULL,
auth_id               integer REFERENCES authentication (id),
ns_id                 integer REFERENCES ns (id),  
UNIQUE (auth_id, ns_id),
PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

ALTER TABLE job
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_auth_id
FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES authentication (id)
ON DELETE CASCADE
DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;

ALTER TABLE job
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_ns_id
FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES ns (id)
ON DELETE CASCADE
DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;

CREATE SEQUENCE job_id_seq
  INCREMENT 1
  MINVALUE 1
  MAXVALUE 2147483647
  START 1
  CACHE 1;
ALTER TABLE job_id_seq
  OWNER TO your_db_user;

ALTER TABLE job ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT nextval('job_id_seq'::regclass);

---------

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS job_metric;

CREATE TABLE job_metric (
  id                       int NOT NULL,       
  j_id                     int NOT NULL REFERENCES job (id), 
  mj_id                   bigint  NOT NULL,
  jm_time                 bigint NOT NULL 
);
CREATE INDEX ON job_metric (jm_time DESC);
CREATE INDEX ON job_metric (jm_time DESC, id);
CREATE INDEX ON job_metric (jm_time DESC, mj_id);

ALTER TABLE job_metric ADD PRIMARY KEY (jm_time, id);

grant all privileges on job_metric to your_db_user;

SELECT create_hypertable('job_metric', 'jm_time' , chunk_time_interval => 604800016);

CREATE SEQUENCE mjob_metric_id_seq
  INCREMENT 1
  MINVALUE 1
  MAXVALUE 2147483647
  START 1
  CACHE 1;
ALTER TABLE mjob_metric_id_seq
  OWNER TO your_db_user;

ALTER TABLE job_metric ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT nextval('mjob_metric_id_seq'::regclass);
---------
```

After creating the tables, I have used the [solution proposed by @Laurenz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64570143/how-to-use-timescale-hypertables-with-foreign-keys-and-keep-a-one-to-many-relati/67744105#67744105) in a database with PostgreSQL 12.6 using the extension of timescaledb 1.7.5 as follows:

**#To fill the table with the appropriate values:**

```
UPDATE job_metric AS jm_point
SET jm_time = qm.time
FROM metrics AS qm
WHERE qm.m_id = jm_point.mj_id;
```

**#Then set it NOT NULL:**

```
ALTER TABLE job_metric ALTER jm_time SET NOT NULL;
```

**#To define your foreign key:**

```
ALTER TABLE job_metric
   ADD FOREIGN KEY (mj_id, jm_time)
   REFERENCES metrics (time, m_id) MATCH FULL;
```

#Response of the last reference table to enable foreign key:                                                                                                   ***Query returned successfully in 40 msec.***

**Expected behavior:**
The idea is to use the table job_metric in an even many-to-many relationship to access the information of job and metrics tables.

**Actual behavior and error:**
Tables are created and FKs were created ***but cannot be used when data is inserted at job_metric*** as is detailed in the following:

```
INSERT INTO job_metric (j_id, mj_id, jm_time) 
VALUES(13, 185063, 1621957192266);
```

> ERROR:  foreign keys to hypertables are not supported CONTEXT:  SQL
> statement " ALTER TABLE _timescaledb_internal._hyper_5_5_chunk ADD
> CONSTRAINT "5_13_job_metric_j_id_mj_id_jm_time_fkey" FOREIGN KEY
> (j_id, mj_id, jm_time) REFERENCES qmetrics("time", m_id) MATCH FULL "
> PL/pgSQL function
> _timescaledb_internal.chunk_constraint_add_table_constraint(_timescaledb_catalog.chunk_constraint)
> line 42 at EXECUTE SQL state: 0A000

***According to https://docs.timescale.com/timescaledb/latest/overview/limitations/##distributed-hypertable-limitations, it looks like the above error is part of the hypertable limitations:

> Foreign key constraints referencing a hypertable are not supported.

**#Request:**
*Given the above information and errors, does anyone know any solution at the DB level to establish the relationships (many-to-many or one-to-many) using timescaledb extension and mainly hypertables?*

> ---

Actually, I have obtained similar of above error when I had attempted to create many-to-many relation among the tables metrics and job_metric using the Django Rest Framework:

```
class Job_Metrics(models.Model):
job = models.OneToOneField(Job, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
metrics = models.ManyToManyField(Metrics)
time = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Running the application metrics pointing out directly metrics_db:
*$ python3 manage.py migrate metrics --database=metrics_db*

> Operations to perform: Apply all migrations: metrics Running migrations: Applying
> metrics.0002_job...Traceback (most recent call last): File
> "/var/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py",
> line 84, in _execute return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
> psycopg2.errors.FeatureNotSupported: foreign keys to hypertables are
> not supported

If someone knows a solution or has an idea to deal with the above error at the REST API level, please could you share your idea with the aim to access data associated tables (metrics and jobs) and modify them together when is required to delete e.g., a job_metric. So far, using hypertables amendments of timescaledb extension seems to be not a viable solution.

Comment: What is the reason to create foreign key constraint? You can create the same schema without the FK contraints and insert data, however you will not get error if you try to violate the constraint. Does it your application insert data? Can you make sure that the application inserts data according your need? (note if you have constraint in PG, your application will fail if violates)

Comment: The reason to use a foreign key constraint is to control the data that can be stored in the foreign key table, it also controls changes to data in the primary key table.

Comment: For example, if the row for a job is deleted from the Job table, and the job's ID is used for job metrics in the Job_Metric table, the relational integrity between the two tables is broken; the deleted job's job metrics will be orphaned in the Job_Metric table without a link to the data in the Job table.

Comment: Importantly the ids and metrics tables are populated by one application X, as the resource and ns by a second application Y, and the authentication, job, and job_metric tables are populated by and consumed from a third application Z.

Comment: 1) `time` is a reserved word (a data type); better not use it as a column name. 2) don't store a time/timestamp in an integer column. Timestamps were invented for storing timestamps.

Comment: @wildplasser good point. Actually, the ids and metrics tables must have time data types and store them as a bigint column in order to work with an application X that populates such tables. Just the ids and metrics tables are working quite well with application X by storing the timestamp of ids and metrics. So, I do not think the time definition of such tables is a problem in this context. Unless you know the issue of foreign keys to hypertables are not supported due to use reserved words as time.

Comment: Why is the maintaining integraty is important for you? Let's say you use just PG and you can define FK. Now when your application inserts data it might fail. Does your application take care of the failure?

Comment: If you need integrity to cascade deletion, then I am not sure it is time series data.
As you noted you cannot define FKs to reference hyper tables. Now I suggest you describe why it is really important to has FKs defined, so somebody can propose a solution.

Comment: Integrity is important due to it is expected to collect metrics (every second by default) from the Metrics table (e.g., metric-a, metric-b) which are added by tables relationship in the foreign key table (i.e. job_metric) that contains the data of the array consumed and populated by the application Z which also can update and delete the data integrated by the job_metric, job, authentication, and ns tables. The array data at application Z point out the table job_metric and the array is composed by: {"job":{},"interval":0,"metrics":[{"metric-a":0.000001,"metric-b":0.0000011}],"ns_id":"string"}.